# Check if user has a song from iTunes in his library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes, media-player

I am building an iPhone app for music album released on iTunes, client requested that if user purchased the album, the app should allow to play these songs in the app while playing games. I need to find a way how to quicly check if the song is available in the iPod library. I've heard that every song from iTunes has some unique ID but I have no idea how to use it. Searching for the name of the song is not an option in library like mine cause I have over 20 gigs of music ...

Thanks,

Ondrej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 20 gigs of music data, not names. Searching for a unique ID involves the same number of searches as for a name, you have the same number of tracks.
What happens if the user bought the CD and ripped it into the iPod?

Comment: I thought there will be some kind of indexing in the db, like in any database syste it would be much faster to search for an id than for a full track name ... :( ... And client doesn't worry about the actual cd as they are prtomoting iTunes sales ...

Comment: Its a database access on a built in indexed sqlite database, covering what is in effect a very small dataset of less than 10,000 items, so I doubt it would be much different, and certainly not the sort of difference that a user would notice.

I can't see anywhere you can search by the ID though, just the query to MPMediaQuery with one of the 'standard' attributes, track/album/group/artist etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can detect which songs in a library are purchased items (that is purchased from iTunes), you can probably detect which songs are purchased from Amazon or other stores, you can detect which songs have been matched with iTunes Match.

But you cannot detect whether a song on the store matches one of the songs in the library. At best you can try to match artist / album title / song title / length of the song, but that does in no way guarantee that you would find all matches.

Comment: Does Apple have any sort of API which will let know the songs/purchases user (say I will provide the name and password for that Apple account) had made, or the number of times he had listened to a track on iTunes?

Comment: Hi @gnasher729 ,How to detect which songs in a library are purchased or not ?

Comment: @somasekhar did you find any solution for detect the songs which are already purchased from the itunes